# Convert Google Drive file url to Google Doc viewer

Tags: c#, google-api

I want to upload an HTML to Google Drive and get the URL. This code upload is good and it returns the URL of the file. But I want get the file URL in Google Doc viewer. How I make it?

```
File body = new File();
body.Title = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item);

//body.Description = "A test document";

body.MimeType = "text/html";
byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(item);

var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = 
    service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "application/vnd.google-apps.document");

request.Convert = true;
request.Upload();
File file = request.ResponseBody;
var id = file.Id;
```